# how i can write this join query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SELECT text 
FROM localization 
LEFT JOIN countries 
ON countries.country_name_key = localization.key 
WHERE countries.country_name_key = localization.key
AND localization.lang = 'ar';
```

I need to write this query in laravel with eloquent model without relations between the model .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? You need to show your attempts whether code in your Models or ideas or problems you have (like why you want to use  Eloquent yet not wanting relationship between models) in order to further aid your helpers or garner more response and answers. Remember code dumping isn't a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I aggree with MrMarlow. Without Eloquent, you have to use Query Builder. But I think, i have different query:

```
$results = DB::table('localization')
         ->leftJoin('countries','countries.country_name_key','localization.key')
         ->where('countries.country_name_key','localization.key')
         ->where('localization.lang', 'ar')
         ->select('localization.text')
         ->get();
```

With leftJoin in the query will show all text in localization table altough no relation in countries. So, i think it no need leftJoin to show localization.text field because you just want to show the localization.text field in localization table only.

It works in laravel 5.6.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Eloquent has to use models with relationships to be able to query effectively, so to the best of my (limited) knowledge, I do not believe it's possible.

However, Laravel does ship with `Query Builder` which will handle this just fine.

### Query Builder

By using the DB facade (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`) you can create the query like so;

```
$results = DB::table('localization')
             ->join('countries', 'localization.key', '=', 'countries.country_name_key')
             ->where('countries.country_name_key', '=', 'localization.key')
             ->where('localization.lang', '=', 'ar')
             ->pluck('text');
```

Documentation for explanation/further research, can be found within the [Laravel 5.6 Query Builder Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

**Edit**

If you do decide you must use eloquent, you can create models for existing database tables using something like [reliese/laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/reliese/laravel), but you would then need to create relationship mapping etc.